# PHP - Laravel 404 in public/storage

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access a file placed in my public storage with a basic HTTP get request. The file is located here:

```
www.example.com/doccenter/file.pdf
```

However, when I try to load that page I get a **404 Error - Not Found** page.

I have tried to run:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

But still not working. I have validated that the file does indeed exist:

```
$ ~/example.com/storage/app/public/doccenter -ls
```

shows:

```
file.pdf
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you are passing wrong path use it like domain.com/storage/your_path_to_diractory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk), `php artisan storage:link` creates a link to `storage/app/public` at `example.com/storage`, so your file is likely at `www.example.com/storage/doccenter/file.pdf`.

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that! When using it locally, it will be `localhost/doccenter/file.pdf`. Your solution works though on a remote! Will accept the answer once SO allows me to :-) Thanks!!